# Possibly faulty ssd?

Tags: ssd, smart

Basically the system boots and runs for some time, but after a while the desktop becomes unresponsive and crashes. In the console (CTRL-ALT-F?), there is a non-stop stream of error logs of type

`systemd-journald[]: failed to write entry, ignoring: read-only file system`

I figured to check the ssd with badblocks and with smartctl tools. But no bad blocks are found; the output of smartctl long test:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     CT240BX500SSD1
Serial Number:    2020E3FBFA53
LU WWN Device Id: 0 000000 000000000
Firmware Version: M6CR013
User Capacity:    240,057,409,536 bytes [240 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 3
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Jul 10 21:31:05 2020 EEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
..........
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       37
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       32
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       7
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       17
180 Unused_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       100
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   068   022   050    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 32 (Min/Max 26/78)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   050    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
202 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0030   100   100   001    Old_age   Offline      -       100
206 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x002e   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
210 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
246 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       1242666346
247 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       38833323
248 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       24196272

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%        33         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%        33         -
# 3  Extended captive    Completed without error       00%        30         -
# 4  Short captive       Completed without error       00%        21         -
# 5  Short offline       Aborted by host               80%        21         -
# 6  Short offline       Aborted by host               80%        21         -
........
```

I'm not familiar with the tool and I'm not sure if I can parse the output correctly, but for me it isn't obvious from the output that the disk is failing.

At first I thought it could be a broken filesystem, but I've tried to format the disk and to reinstall the OS, and the problem persists.

So is this a broken ssd which doesn't want to admit it?

The OS that was used is Kali Linux 2020.2 (from their website). But I doubt that the software would cause this.

SSD brand and model: crucial bx500 240gb

Comment: I had a Sandisk fail in a similar way, drive would be fine but after some length of time would simply stop responding and the system would fall over. It would be fine after a reboot and everything would carry on until the next time. Formatting, running manufacturer tools or other things didn't fix it, replacing the drive did.

Comment: The temperature has been up to 78C max, which is a bit too hot. You should also check the journalctl logs to see what disk error the system saw.